# Delete Cascade without changing table structure

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, sql-delete, cascade

My database is polluted with test data and I want clean up some rows.
If I try to delete, i get message that a foreign key constraint fails.
If possible I want to avoid changing the table structure (adding ON CASCADE)

I tried something like this:

```
DELETE from transactions WHERE itemID = (SELECT itemID from items WHERE price=0);
DELETE from items WHERE price=0;
```

but this doesn't work, because the subselect isn't allowed to return multiple rows. i assume it is possible to do some magic with loops, but I have zero experience in using those (answers without loops are also appreciated ;))

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE items (itemID int, price int, description varchar(30), PRIMARY KEY(itemID));
CREATE TABLE transactions (transactionID int, itemID int, PRIMARY KEY (transactionID) , FOREIGN KEY (itemID) REFERENCES items(itemID));
INSERT INTO items VALUES (1, 0, "TEST");
INSERT INTO items VALUES (2, 0, "TEST2");
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES (1, 2);
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES (2, 2);
INSERT INTO transactions VALUES (3, 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be resolved by replacing '=' with 'IN' so that your SQL reads as follows:

```
DELETE from transactions WHERE itemID IN (SELECT itemID from items WHERE price=0);
DELETE from items WHERE price=0;
```

I hope this helps...